# how to pass object between ViewModels using windowmanager caliburn micro wpf

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, window-managers

I have `AddEditViewModel` and `AddEditView` associated with it. I want to start dialog window from `ViewModel2` using `IWindowManager` object. The code from `ViewModel2` class:

```
windowManager.ShowDialog(new AddEditViewModel(_windowManager,_events), 
this.SelectedCar, settings);
```

but I don't know how to recover the object `this.SelectedCar` in the `AddEditViewModel`? Is it possible ?

Comment: Is it still a problem or you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the object after the dialog has been shown:

```
var model = new AddEditViewModel(_windowManager, _events);

dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject(); 
settings.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow; 
settings.ShowInTaskbar = true; 
settings.Title = "This is a custom title";

var result = windowManager.ShowDialog(model, null, settings);

var car = model.SelectedCar;
```